# Combine dynamic columns with select query

Tags: postgresql, select, dynamic

I am using a [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database. I have one select query:

```
select userid, name, age from tbluser;
```

Now there is another table, `tblcalculatedtax`, which is generated on the fly and their column names are not predefined, the only mapping between that table and this table is `userid`. I want to get records after joining two tables. How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbluser 
JOIN   tblcalculatedtax USING (userid)
```

Details in the fine [manual about SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your need SQL Joins. Here's a W3Schools tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

To quickly answer your question, though:

```
SELECT * FROM tbluser 
  INNER JOIN tblcalculatedtax 
  ON tbluser.userid=tblcalculatedtext.userid
```

The * selects all the columns, so you don't need to know their names. Of course, I'm not sure what use a column is to you if you don't know it's name: do you know what data it contains?

Comment: I have one table that contains invoice details and another that contains difference tax for that perticular invoice but i dont know that name of tax and i want to map that table with tax table of invoice.